# i2c probe not being called....not sure where to call i2c_register_board_info

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, i2c

I have an Intel systems. I am trying to load at24.ko and i2c-mux-pca9541.ko.
both modules have probe functions which are not being called.
according to the Documentation, i need to call i2c_registetr_board_info in the arch_init.
but I am not sure where to do that for the Intel system (ie which files).
I do not see any examples anywhere on the internet.
can someone provide a pointer to the file that i add this call.
if this is not the right approach, please let me know.

thank you in advance.

Comment: What kernel version are you using? Are you using a device tree? Is the I2C interface defined in the device tree?

Comment: Hi, i am using 3.14. i am not using device tree. i tried adding i2c_register_board_info under i2c-i801 (since this is the i2c adapter) but got compile error saying "i2c_register_board_info' not defined. i had to explicitly export the function to get around the compile issue, and still can not get the probe to be called. for intel system, it seems there's something else that shoudl be done..

Comment: "i2c_register_board_info" is defined in drivers/i2c/i2c-boardinfo.c so putting it in i2c-i1801, as you did, is not a solution. Do you have CONFIG_I2C_BOARDINFO enabled in your .config file?

Comment: hi sessy. yes it's enabled. i also checked system.map and the function is listed in the file.

Comment: What Intel system do you have exactly? Do you have a board file for it like  `arch/arm/mach-omap2/myboard.c`?

Comment: @yegorich the file you mentioned will probably not be compiled in an Intel build of Linux. As the path says, it is for ARM. vcho, in other plaforms i.e. ARM, the call to "i2c_register_board_info" is performed early during the achitecture initialization. It has an "__init" function that is called early. This then calls "i2c_register_board_info". See arch/x86/platform/intel-mid/sfi.c or arch/arm/plat-omap/i2c.c in your Linux source tree.

Comment: @vcho , can you kindly let me know whether you were able to add the i2c_register_board_info in appropriate file related with Intel processor. Can you kindly share me the name/path of the file in which it was added for reference ?

Answer (score 4):

The probe is not called because a "matching" device is not found by the kernel that could be associated with the driver. There are different ways to provide the device information to the kernel. They are discussed as follows :

If this is for testing purpose, you can probe the i2c devices through sysfs :

`echo <device_name> <i2c_address> > /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-0/new_device`

`device_name` : name of the i2c device. Should be the one used in the driver.

`i2c_address` : Address of the i2c device as per the device datasheet

The above command assumes that the i2c bus '0' is the one where the device is attached.

Apart from this, there are some other ways to probe your device. You might specify the device info through a device tree or by calling `i2c_register_board_info()`. You could create a simple module that creates the `i2c_board_info` structure and registers it using `i2c_register_board_info()`, and then insert the module such that the device would be "known" to the kernel and binds the device with its driver. It need not be in the board init codes.

I recommend you to go through the following documentation on probing i2c devices : http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/i2c/instantiating-devices

Comment: thanks, this help me alot. but where to pass the `platform_data` of `i2c_board_info`